# R: finding the source code that produces the output for S4 slot?

Tags: r, r-s4, slot, lme4, lmer

G'day Everyone,

When the 'lmer' function in 'lme4' runs its produces an S4 object with a lot of slots. I am interested in one of these slots, namely model@X, and how this 'X' slot output is produced. I want to try reproduce this output for a different model function (glmmPQL) I am using which does not automatically produces this 'X' output (FYI 'lmer' produces an object of class 'mer', and slot 'X' is a model matrix for the fixed effects). **Code below shows what I am talking about.**

What I want to figure out is how the produced this 'X' data? I looked at the code for 'lmer' by writing it in the terminal without '()' but I couldn't find anything there. I also tried showMethod('lmer') but it says function 'lmer': .

Just wondering if there is a way to get the source code for what the 'X' slot is doing in particular (or any slot in a S4 object)? Or does anyone know how to reproduce this? Thanks lots for your help and time.

```
    library(lme4)
    # here is a quick example of what I am looking at using the cake dataset in the 'lme4' package
    m <- lmer(cakeglmm<- lmer(angle ~ temp + recipe + (1| replicate), family = gaussian, data = cake)

    slotNames(m)
    head(m@X)
```

Comment: You can get the source code to every R package, including the core, at CRAN.

Answer (score 1):

You started off okay by printing `lmer`. That won't show you where `m@X` is set, but you can see which methods are called by `lmer`.

The methods within `lmer` can be accessed using `lme4:::methodName`.

If you look inside `lme4:::lmer_finalize`, you'll see (paraphrasing):

```
ans <- new(Class = "mer", ..., X = fr$X, ...)
```

So that's where the `@X` slot is being populated. Back up in `lmer` you'll see that `fr` comes from `lme4:::lmerFrames`, and specifically `fr$X` is calculated by:

```
X <- if (!is.empty.model(mt)) 
    model.matrix(mt, mf, contrasts)
else matrix(, NROW(Y), 0)
```